# USB3 HDD does not spin down after selecting "Eject drive"

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb-3

my external WD drive connected to USB3 on home PC spin down after selecting "Eject drive" but it does not spin down on work PC (on USB3 as well). Tried to find answers in Google but I could not. I checked and cannot find any power management on USB3 in Device Manager...
Do you know what I can look at?

Comment: 1) Please edit your question to include make/model info of your computers and the model of your external WD HDD. 2) Does Windows report that the device is ready for removal when you eject it on your work PC?

Answer (score 0):

Most WD external drives spin down automatically after a few minutes of inactivity; it appears that at work, your PC or a network server is continually accessing the HD.
To remove it safely, you might need to disconnect from the network or shut down the PC first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for answering.
[USBView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/Ff560019(v=VS.85).aspx) showed that ports were configured as USB3.
After error and trial process of changing BIOS settings I found what need to be set in BIOS to make it USB3.
If i recall it right all three has to be checked.
- USB charging
- USB power on
- USB legacy support
Once port became USB3 drive spins down right after selecting to safely remove it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MS KB 2401954](https://support.microsoft.com/zh-tw/kb/2401954), it is no longer need to spin down the drive for Windows Vista or later.

> When a USB device is Disabled in Device Manager or Safely Removed using the system tray icon, a Remove Device request (PnP IRP IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE) is issued to perform a "Soft Removal" of the USB device. The USB device is marked as Removed for Plug and Play purposes, although the device has not been physically disconnected yet.

However, if you still want to spin down the drive when clicking eject, following the following steps:

[image]